# Querying Solr Config API returns Internal Server Error

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I'm attempting to update my solr config via the Solr Config API. I attempting to first query the config with the following endpoint:

http://localhost:8983/solr//config

the response I get back is 500 Internal Server Error and I noticed in logs for the deployed solr the following exception:

```
Internal Server Error (500) - No RestManager found!
at org.apache.solr.rest.RestManager.getRestManager(RestManager.java:245)
at org.apache.solr.rest.SolrConfigRestApi.createInboundRoot(SolrConfigRestApi.java:67)
at org.restlet.Application.getInboundRoot(Application.java:270)
at org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.start(ApplicationHelper.java:127)
at org.restlet.Application.start(Application.java:582)
```

The core was created using the following post:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=<keyspace.table>&generateResources=true&reindex=true"
```

This action was successful but a GET to the config api fails.

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url should be: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/[ks.cf]/config

Still there are convenience/recommended methods to avoid you all the curl commands. See:

- dsetool create_core
- dsetool get_core_config
- dsetool get_core_schema
- dsetool reload_core

In your case a dsetool create_core, dsetool get_core_config, modify the solrconfig.xml and a later dsetool reload_core with the new solrconfig should get you what you need. See: [Dsetool doc](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/tools/toolsDsetool.html) for usage details

If you need some examples on how to do that with curl, if you still need to use curl, see the shell files under the wikipedia demo, 1-add-schema.sh for instance. Still dsetool commands are the recommended method.

If you intended to use the Solr Config API please notice this is Solr 5 feature and in DSE you will find version 4.10 so that feature is not available yet. If you want to change the solr config you will have to reload with the new solrconfig using the outlined dsetool commands above.

It would be very useful to know the exact version you are using.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not sure why the documentation doesn't state the '#' but this works. I'm working in a vm container env. Scripting the config updates via curl is more predicable than finding the path for the dsetool.